# Assign new value in a 2d array list (Dict)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to assign new values in a 2d list of my dictionary. Here's my code:

```
DictUP_Days = {'2': [('None', 'Friday'), ('Any', 'Saturday'), ('Any', 'Sunday')]}
S = ['E', 'L', 'D', 'N']
NewDict = {}

for key, value in DictUP_Days.items():
    for shift, days in value:
            if shift == 'None':
                newDict[key] = '',days
            elif shift == 'Any':
                newDict[key] = S,days
```

If I print out my `newDict` I get : `{'2': (['E', 'L', 'D', 'N'], 'Sunday')}`. The program only keep the last item in my list (Sunday).

The expected output should look like this: `{'2': ('', 'Friday'),(['E', 'L', 'D', 'N'], 'Saturday'),(['E', 'L', 'D', 'N'], 'Sunday')}`. Can you show me where's my mistake plz ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with in-place updating of your dict:

```
DictUP_Days = {'2': [('None', 'Friday'), ('Any', 'Saturday'), ('Any', 'Sunday')]}
S = ['E', 'L', 'D', 'N']
for key, value in DictUP_Days.items():
    for index, (shift, days) in enumerate(value):
            if shift == 'None':
                value[index] = '',days
            elif shift == 'Any':
                value[index] = S,days

print(DictUP_Days)
```

The above outputs:

```
{'2': [('', 'Friday'), (['E', 'L', 'D', 'N'], 'Saturday'), (['E', 'L', 'D', 'N'], 'Sunday')]}
```